# OpenVPN 4in6 or 4over6 tunnel

Tags: openvpn, ipv6, tunnel, ipv4

My ISP sucks. It gives me an IPv6 Address and an IPv4 one, but IPv4 is down 50% of the time (I can't access any IPv4 Services every 10 minutes)...

As I already have an OpenVPN Server set up, I asked myself if it's possible to tunnel all my IPv4 traffic from my home PC through the IPv6 connection to my VPN.

`PC <---IPv6---> VPN <---IPv4---> Service`

I don't know if that scenario is an "4in6" or an "4over6" tunnel. Anyway, I'm not able to find any detailed setup guide for that. Is this possible using OpenVPN?

Here is my *current setup*:

**Server**

/etc/openvpn/server.conf

```
port 443
proto udp
dev tun
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/dh4096.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1"
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ta.key 0
comp-lzo
max-clients 2
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
log-append  openvpn.log
verb 3
```

ifconfig

```
tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  Hardware Adresse 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet Adresse:10.8.0.1  P-z-P:10.8.0.2  Maske:255.255.255.255
          UP PUNKTZUPUNKT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
```

**Client**

/etc/openvpn/client.conf

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remove IPv4.OF.THE.SRV 443
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
ca /etc/openvpn/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/keys/client1.crt
key /etc/openvpn/keys/client1.key
ns-cert-type server
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/keys/ta.key 1
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

Any chance this can be transformed into something I can use for my case? Additionally (optional): Any obvious mistakes in my config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. It is called OpenVPN transport over IPv6. You will see quite a few references to this on Google. In particular [this Web page](http://www.toofishes.net/blog/ipv6-follow-openvpn-transport-over-ipv6/) tells you how to configure a Tun interface to do just what you are asking for. It is truly a minor adjustment.